# How to call method from innerHTML.?

Tags: javascript, html

My problem are concerning these 2 methods. DisplayBookmark(), and deleteBookmark(). Display bookmark has an url. When I press button delete I need to take that url, and put into deleteBookmark() method. I need to modify this line:
 `<a class="button button__delete">Delete</a>` [Codepen example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pqGjgX?editors=1010)

[Similiar example] line 88 (https://github.com/bradtraversy/bookmarker/blob/master/js/main.js) but with ES5 syntax

My thoughts:

- I can't create url as class property because it tied to bookmark array
- I tried using `${onclick = this.deleteBookmark(url)}` However now it launches whenever I activate displayBookmark(). I need it only when I click delete.
- I can't select button__delete because it doesn't exist immediately.

Thanks in advance

HTML

```
  <div class="wrapper">
        <form id="bookmarkFormID" class="bookmarkForm">
            <h3 class="bookmarkForm__title">Bookmark your Favourite Sites</h3>
            <p class="bookmarkForm__p">Website Name</p>
            <input id="siteName" type="text" placeholder="Website Name">
            <p class="bookmarkForm__p">Website URL</p>
            <input id="siteURL" type="text"  placeholder="Website URL">
            <input class="submitButton" type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="bookmarkResults">  
        </div>
    </div>
```

Javascript

```
class Bookmark {
    constructor(){
        // Properties
        this.siteName               = document.getElementById('siteName');
        this.siteURL                = document.getElementById('siteURL');
        this.bookmarkForm           = document.getElementById('bookmarkFormID');
        this.bookmarksResults       = document.querySelector('.bookmarkResults');

        // Methods
        this.bookmarkForm.addEventListener('submit', event => this.saveBookmarks(event))

        this.validateForm;
        this.displayBookmark;

        this.events();

    }
    events(){
    this.displayBookmark();
    }
    // Save bookmark data and implements local storage
    saveBookmarks(event){

       //  Implements Local Storage
        let bookmarkObject = {
            siteName: siteName.value,
            siteUrl:  siteURL.value
        }

        if(localStorage.getItem("bookmarks") === null){
            let bookmarks = [];
            bookmarks.push(bookmarkObject)
            localStorage.setItem("bookmarks", JSON.stringify(bookmarks));
        }else{
            let bookmarks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("bookmarks"));
            bookmarks.push(bookmarkObject);
            localStorage.setItem("bookmarks", JSON.stringify(bookmarks));
        }
        // Resets form
        this.bookmarkForm.reset();

        this.displayBookmark();
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    // Display bookmark on DOM
    displayBookmark(){
       let bookmarks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("bookmarks"));
        // If local storage is empty.
        if(bookmarks == null){
            return false;
        }else{
            this.bookmarksResults.innerHTML = ``;
            for (let index = 0; index < bookmarks.length; index++) {
            let name = (bookmarks[index].siteName).charAt(0).toUpperCase() + bookmarks[index].siteName.slice(1);
            let url = bookmarks[index].siteUrl;
            console.log("url is " + url);
            this.bookmarksResults.innerHTML += 
            `
            <ul>
                <li><h2 ><a class="bookmarkResults__title" href="${url}" target="_blank">${name}</a></h2>
                <a class="button button__delete">Delete</a>
                <a class="button button__edit">Edit</a>
                <a class="button button__visit" href="${url}" target="_blank">Visit</a>
                </li>
            </ul>   
            `
            }  
        }
    }
    deleteBookmark(url){    
        let bookmarks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("bookmarks"));
        for (let index = 0; index < bookmarks.length; index++) {
            if(bookmarks[index].siteUrl == url){
                console.log("is it working?");
                bookmarks.splice(index, 1); 
            } 
        }
        localStorage.setItem(bookmarks, JSON.stringify(bookmarks));
    }
}
const bookmark = new Bookmark;
```

Comment: Instead of `${onclick = this.deleteBookmark(url)}`, use `this.bookmarksResults.addEventListener("click", ({target}) => { if(target.matches(".button__delete")){ this.deleteBookmark(url); } });` in your constructor. This uses event delegation. Your attempt looks like event attributes, which are very problematic.

Comment: I added your code in my bookmarksResults.innerHTML on button__delete. It solved 2 of my problems. deleteBookmark has url parameter. And it only activates if I click delete.

Comment: On further inspection. Your code didn't worked because If you have multiple bookmarks clicking delete will delete all of them. Instead of only one. That happens because every bookmark has .button__delete class.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you to dynamically create DOM for your `ul`, not just using innerHTML.
Create all the elements via `var list = document.createElement('ul');` and append with `this.bookmarksResults.appendChild(list)` after that when you have button created with js: `var deleteButton = document.createElement('a');` you can simply add event listener to it. Also I'd suggest you to use `button` instead of `a`:

```
var ul = document.createElement('ul');
var deleteButton = document.createElement('button');
deleteButton.addEventListener('click', function(bookmark) {
  // do something with bookmark here
}.bind(bookmarks[index]));
ul.appendChild(deleteButton);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to delegate the click event (for delete) to the ul element.

you can use the matches method on the element to validate which element was clicked.

```
onListClick(e) {
 var button = e.target;
 // TODO Validate if target is a button

 if (button.matches([DETELE_CLASS])) {
   this.deleteBook(button.dataset);
 } else if (button.matches([UPDATE_CLASS])) {
   this.editBook(button.dataset);
 }

}
```

E.g

```js
class Bookmark {
  constructor() {
    this.handleDelete = this.handleDelete.bind(this);
    this.handleAdd = this.handleAdd.bind(this);
    
    this.cachedElements();
    this.bindEventListeners();
  }
  
  cachedElements() {
    this.bookInput = document.querySelector('#book-input');
    this.bookList = document.querySelector('#book-list');
    this.bookForm = document.querySelector('#book-form');
  }
  
  bindEventListeners() {
    this.bookForm.addEventListener('submit', this.handleAdd);
    this.bookList.addEventListener('click', this.handleDelete);
  }
  
  createBook(bookName) {
     const bookItem = (`
        <li>
          <span>${bookName}</span>
          <button data-name="${bookName}">x</button>
        </li>
     `);
     this.bookList.innerHTML += bookItem;
  }
  
  handleAdd(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    this.createBook(this.bookInput.value);
    this.bookInput.value = '';
  }
  
  handleDelete(e) {
    var button = e.target;
    //TODO add more validation 
    if (button.nodeName !== 'BUTTON') { return; }
   
    button.parentNode.remove()
    
  }
  
}

new Bookmark();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>

</head>
<body>
 <div>
   <div>
     <form id="book-form">
       <input type="text" id="book-input">
     </form>
   </div>
   <ul id="book-list"></ul>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```